# Simple array access (or list) doesn't work

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a very simple problem that I unfortunately can't solve.
I use an API that returns an object that I convert to json to push it into my database, but I can't access the elements of this array (I don't know if it's multi-dimensional or not).

This is the json :

```
[
  [
    5.788894,
    46.391834
  ],
  [
    5.788879,
    46.392345
  ],
  [
    5.788877,
    46.39241
  ]
]
```

And this this the object of the API :

[API object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9oQW.png)

How should my loop be to retrieve the latitude and longitude of each point?
Thank you very much for your help;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If I don't misunderstood your question and requirements** then lets try like this way,

```
<?php
 $json = '[[5.788894,46.391834],[5.788879,46.392345],[5.788877,46.39241]]';
 $array = json_decode($json,1); // decode json to array

 //just for debug
 print '<pre>';
 print_r($array);
 print '<pre>';

 foreach($array as $row){
    echo "latitude = $row[0] and longitude = $row[1]".PHP_EOL;   
 }
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/U1F1n

Comment: @cpt_3n0x You're welcome, glad it works and help you somehow. Best of luck :)